# .htaccess on root broke everything

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, apache2

I was gonna redirect non-www to www and copied this on .htaccess

```
# Generated by esoTalk
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htts://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But Instead of https I write htts by mistake. And another mistake is I sent it instead inside directory of public_html,to upper root directory. And It's just gone. I can't find with find -name "*." command or I can't delete it on the root doing rm .htaccess Basically I can't access it but It broke the site I got ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the non-www urls.

What I done in order to solve this:

- Restarted apache
- rebooted the vps
- sending another .htaccess file to root which has correct https line

Nothing changed even I send a new same named .htaccess file the error didn't change still got a problem because of "htts"

Information:

Server version: Apache/2.4.10
Distro: Debian 8

Answer (score 0):

Check for any `.htaccess` files with

```
find /your/web/root -name ".htaccess" -print
```

Then have just one `.htaccess` file, or a virtual host config, that performs HTTPS and domain checks first. Having a condition for `%{HTTPS}` should prevent your infinite redirects because it will skip the action when the request is already being handled over HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Didn't work. I have root access on my vps, how do I actually terminate my  hidden erorrous .htaccess on upper root.

Comment: @Soner See my edit. Find any extra .htaccess files and delete them.  No need to restart apache.

Comment: That' is the problem there is no .htaccess file like anywhere but public html. Is there another file type like temporary hidden which we wouldn't evetn see with find? I can't think anything else. I really couldnt find it

Comment: @Soner It's either `.htaccess` or set directly in your virtual host config file. Check your Apache config.  Technically you could have a config setting that calls .htaccess something else but few would bother.